# liquibase corrupting UTF-8 changesets

Tags: encoding, utf-8, liquibase

I'm using Liquibase 2.0.5 (but have already tested with newest 3.2.0 to no avail) and when I try to update MySQL 5.5 database with SQL changesets consisting UTF-8 characters all seem to get converted to ASCII as instead of polish letters I get "?".

Here is the command I'm using:

```
java -jar liquibase.jar --changeLogFile=changesets.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname" --username=user --password=pass --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --classpath=mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar update
```

changeset.xml is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

  <include file="Changesets/2014.26/changesets.xml"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Changesets/2014.26/changesets.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

    <changeSet id="20140623_1700" author="tmarcinkowski">
        <sqlFile path="Changesets/2014.26/20140623_1700_tmarcinkowski_ss_303.sql"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

And finally... Changesets/2014.26/20140623_1700_tmarcinkowski_ss_303.sql:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog` (`category_id`, `parent_category_id`, `name`, `priority`, `photo`, `icon_catalog`, `icon_breadcrumbs`, `lft`, `rgt`) VALUES
(0, NULL, 'root', 0, '', '', '', 1, 1262),
(1, 0, 'Art. spożywcze', 1, '', '', '', 2, 755),
(2, 1, 'Owoce i Warzywa', 4, '', '', '', 3, 60),
(3, 1, 'Nabiał', 2, '', '', '', 61, 146),
(4, 1, 'Mięso, Wędliny', 5, '', '', '', 147, 206),
(5, 1, 'Ryby i Owoce morza', 9, '', '', '', 207, 234),
(6, 1, 'Mrożonki i lody', 10, '', '', '', 235, 266),
(7, 1, 'Pieczywo', 1, '', '', '', 267, 324);
```

Appending --logLevel=debug shows already corrupted characters.

```
DEBUG 6/25/14 11:17 AM:liquibase: SQLFile file:Changesets/2014.26/20140623_1700_tmarcinkowski_ss_303.sql
DEBUG 6/25/14 11:17 AM:liquibase: SQLFile file contents is:

INSERT INTO `catalog` (`category_id`, `parent_category_id`, `name`, `priority`, `photo`, `icon_catalog`, `icon_breadcrumbs`, `lft`, `rgt`) VALUES
(0, NULL, 'root', 0, '', '', '', 1, 1262),
(1, 0, 'Art. spo?ywcze', 1, '', '', '', 2, 755),
(2, 1, 'Owoce i Warzywa', 4, '', '', '', 3, 60),
(3, 1, 'Nabia?', 2, '', '', '', 61, 146),
(4, 1, 'Mi?so, W?dliny', 5, '', '', '', 147, 206),
(5, 1, 'Ryby i Owoce morza', 9, '', '', '', 207, 234),
(6, 1, 'Mro?onki i lody', 10, '', '', '', 235, 266),
(7, 1, 'Pieczywo', 1, '', '', '', 267, 324);
```

Appending "useJvmCharsetConverters=true" and "charSet=UTF-8" to connection string doesn't help either, just as adding "SET NAMES utf8;" at the beginning of a changeset.
All files are UTF-8.

Does anyone know how to handle it?

Comment: Seems like a bug. Can you open an issue at liquibase.jira.com and attach your actual .sql file (to ensure file BOM settings and everything is correct).

Comment: Hi guys, is there any developments in this issue? I remember very clearly that I've posted the issue on github but I cannot find it now. Do new version of liquidbase support non latin characters? Where is the issue tracker?

Answer (score 5):

This is Connector/J issue: Since v5.1.3 Connector/J auto-detects servers configured with character_set_server=utf8mb4 or treats the Java encoding utf-8 passed using characterEncoding=xxx as utf8mb4.

Just add useUnicode and characterEncoding parameters to MySQL connection URL.

In command line:

```
-url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

or in liquibase.properties file:

```
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```